# How to catch non-ASCII characters in input stream C++

Tags: c++

I want to read some user input and check if there is any [non-printable](https://www.ascii-code.com/) ASCII character in the input, such as '‰'

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string password;
    cin >> password;

    for (unsigned char c : password)
    {
        cout << c << endl;
        cout << (int)c << endl;
        if ((int)c < 32 || (int)c > 127)
        {
            printf(" ! Invalid password inserted !\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This does not work, because `(int)c` for '‰' returns 37 when it is actually 137.

```
    unsigned char c = '‰';
    cout << (int)c << endl;
```

This, however, does return the desired 137.

Comment: i think it doesnt actually matter for the question, but how is ‰ not printable?

Comment: Your question's title is about detecting characters above 127, but the body implies that the problem is printing it back. Which is it? (That `if` condition works fine)

Comment: `‰` is not an ASCII character. If you see this character, the very first thing you should ask yourself is "what charset and encoding am I using?" And you should include the answer as the first sentence of your question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Maybe it's just bad wording on my part. I was just referring to this website https://www.ascii-code.com/ where it defines ASCII characters 32-127 as 'printable', 0-31 as 'control characters', and 128-255 as 'extended ASCII' codes. What I'm interesting in detecting ar characters outside of the 32-127 range.

Comment: Look up functions in the standard header `<cctype>` such as `std::isprint()`  (which tests for a printable character in the current locale).   You might want to check your definition of "printable" to ensure it aligns with that checked by those functions.

Comment: Don't trust anyone who tells you that "extended ASCII" is a thing.

Comment: Can you explain how you expect to have that character -- whose Unicode value is U+2030, and will either be represented as a Unicode character 8240 or a multi-byte UTF-8 sequence -- fit inside a single `unsigned char`, whose capacity ends at a grand total of 8 bits?

Comment: @DannyG you should read about encodings. Both your question and your comments show you do not understand your own question. Read about how text is actually encoded into bytes. What are codepoints, codeunits and when encoding conversion is needed. — `unsigned char c = '‰';` already does not do what you think it does.

Comment: [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) has `‰` encoded as 137 value.  Is your input stream also Windows-1252?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you compare the input to `'‰'`, you won't find it.

Comment: If you enter _only_ `‰` and then do `std::cout << password.size() << '\n';` you may get a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::isprint` from the C++ standard library.

It has the advantage that it's portable, expressions like `((int)c < 32 || (int)c > 127)` are not.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint

Comment: That does not solve the problem. The main issue is he tries to read from a byte stream in without accounting for the actual encoding.